# How to shorten my url if im using github pages to host my site?

Tags: html, url, url-rewriting, web-deployment, github-pages

(both links include "https://" in front when entered into google)

if my current URL is: thecrtr.com/home.htm

and I would like: thecrtr.com

what would you recommend? (I am using git hub pages to host the site and in which I have many files in my "gh-pages branch", so I feel like this specification in the URL in necessary to locate the correct file the site should open upon loading. I have tried many different approaches. However, sites like apple.com do not have this issue. Please help. Thank you.)

Comment: Try renaming your home.htm to index.html. Also, if that service supports .htaccess files, you should look into it to route thecrtr.com to thecrtr.com/home.htm

Comment: Renaming the file worked! thanks keanu_reeves